# PHP Search CSV script

Tags: php, csv

How do I add an if statement to search another csv file? This php file [PHP script searches CSV text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250476/php-script-searches-csv-text-file) here is generating the form base on csv file. I want the user able to chose to search from two separate csv files on the same page

```
include('csvtoservice.php');
$content = csvtoservice(
    'http://www.scgstudio.com/ucsc/web/Workbook3.csv',
    array(
        'filter' => array(fieldnames),
        'rename' => array(
            'name' => 'Name',
            'donortype' => 'Donor Type',
            'year' => 'Year',
            'amount' => 'Amount'
        ),
        'uppercase' => Boolean
    )
);


if ($content) {
    // show the form
    echo '<h2>Honor Roll of 2010-11 Contributors</h2>';
    if ($content['form']) {
        echo $content['form'];
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is impossible to understand correctly. Do you actually mean CSV *file*, or a different directory?

In any case, change the string 'http://www.scgstudio.com/ucsc/web/Workbook3.csv' to whatever else you need.

Also you don't mention what exactly you want the "if" statement to ask for, so the question cannot be answered. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at using a loop like `foreach()` and replace the url you are using with `$url` from the example below.

```
$urls = array('http://www.scgstudio.com/ucsc/web/Workbook3.csv',
              'http://www.scgstudio.com/ucsc/web2/Workbook3.csv',
              'http://www.scgstudio.com/ucsc/web3/Workbook3.csv');

include('csvtoservice.php');

foreach($urls as $url) {
...
<your code here>
...
}
```